# Don't dismiss keyboard when presenting popup menu on a custom view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, keyboard, uimenucontroller

I created my own UIView subclass to present text information to the user. User is able to double tap this view to popup a 'Copy' menu. The problem is that UITextView within the same view controller resigns its first responder status thus dismissing keyboard when popup menu is presented. How do I avoid this? I want my application to behave like standard iPhone's Messages application: keyboard is not dismissed while double tapping on message bubble presents a popup menu.

Answer (score 0):

keep the refrence of UITextView . and in selector of message bubble make text view first
 responder eg-
`popUpclicked{
[textView becomefirstResponder]
}`

or make userinteractionEnable property to NO may be it work...

Comment: I found a better solution: if keyboard is active, it shows popup menu for the message bubble.

Comment: @sgosha : can you explain your solution? It would be a great help.